# Implementing drop down in Angular2

Tags: angular

Is there a better way to implement a drop down in Angular2

I am doing the following

In the template

```
<select (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
                      <option *ngFor="#taskstatus of dropdownValues" [value]="taskstatus.value">{{taskstatus.name}}</option>
</select>
```

In the component class

```
export class CreateTaskComponent {

    public selectedStatus: Taskstatus = this.dropdownValues[0];
    public dropdownValues: Taskstatus[] = [
         {"name":"OPEN","value":"OPEN"},
         {"name":"CLOSED","value":"CLOSED"}
    ];

    onSelect(taskevent) { 
        this.selectedStatus = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.dropdownValues.length; i++)
        {
          if (this.dropdownValues[i].value == taskevent) {
            this.selectedStatus = this.dropdownValues[i];
            console.log(this.selectedStatus.value);
          }
        }
    }
}

class Taskstatus{
  name: string;
  value: string;
}
```

Is there a simpler approach to this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ngModel` and `ngValue` like:

```ts
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedStatus">
  <option *ngFor="#taskstatus of dropdownValues" [ngValue]="taskstatus">{{taskstatus.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: everything else stays the same ?

Comment: You don't need the `onSelect` method. Otherwise all can stay the same.

Comment: Ups, forgot square brackets around `ngModel` - added.